# How can I merge two function definitions in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, definition

I have the following `create` function, which have two definitions:

```js
// Definition 1
export async function create<Entity>(
  entity: ObjectType<Entity>,
  data: DeepPartial<Entity>
): Promise<Entity>;

// Definition 2 
export async function create<Entity>(
  entity: ObjectType<Entity>,
  data: DeepPartial<Entity>,
  pickValues: keyof Entity
): Promise<Partial<Entity>>;

// Implementation
export async function create<Entity>(
  entity: ObjectType<Entity>,
  data: DeepPartial<Entity>,
  pickValues?: keyof Entity
): Promise<Entity | Partial<Entity>> {
  const { manager } = await connectDatabase();

  const instance = manager.create(entity, data);
  const createdEntity = await manager.save(instance);

  return typeof pickValues === 'undefined'
    ? createdEntity
    : pick(createdEntity, pickValues);
}
```

Is there a way to merge those two definitions in the typings of the function implementation? Maybe with a conditional return type... Something like this:

```
A extends B ? c : d;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed possible to use a conditional return type for this. What we need to do is introduce a generic type for the `pickValues` argument so we can use it for the return type:

```js
export async function create<Entity, PickValues extends keyof Entity | undefined = undefined>(
  entity: ObjectType<Entity>,
  data: DeepPartial<Entity>,
  pickValues?: PickValues
): Promise<PickValues extends undefined ? Entity : Partial<Entity>> {
  const { manager } = await connectDatabase();

  const instance = manager.create(entity, data);
  const createdEntity = await manager.save(instance);

  return (typeof pickValues === 'undefined'
    ? createdEntity
    : pick(createdEntity, pickValues as keyof Entity)) as any;
}
```

Unfortunately due to design limitations in TypeScript it doesn't really understand that the return type should be different based on the value of `pickValues` [(github issue)](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22735). Because of this we have to cast the return value to `any` to make it work.

Because of the necessary casts and the added complexity I would recommend to stick with the overloads for better readability.

---

Note: TypeScript actually has a utility type `Pick` which should allow you to be even more specific. Instead of `Partial<Entity>` you could use `Pick<Entity, Exclude<Values, undefined>>` in the return type.

Comment: Yes, I tried to use this kind of generic type, but I get this error: `Type 'Partial<Entity>' is not assignable to type 'PickValues extends undefined ? Entity : Partial<Entity>'.ts(2322)`. [See it here](https://i.imgur.com/DGjKII5.png).

Comment: Sorry I've made a mistake in the code example. The argument `pickValues` should have the type `PickValues`. Answer is updated.

Comment: Hmm although I don't think that will fix the error... I'll try and figure out what the issue is.

Comment: Yes, I came along that error too. The error message is [this](https://i.imgur.com/3S3haZY.png). After these two errors I _give up_ to the 2 functions overloads. :p But I am pretty sure that it is possible to create that in a single function declaration...

Comment: So it seems that getting this to work would require to cast the return value. ([see this github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22735))
In addition to that you might also have to cast `pickValues` to `keyof PickValues` before passing it to `pick`.

Comment: Even if it works with all these casts... I would probably prefer the two overloads instead. Mainly because they are easier to read and understand.

Comment: No worries. I'm kind of bummed out myself that it didn't work out nicely. I've updated the answer with the casts and info about why they're needed.